# Starting Blender via Java-Code and autorun a script

Tags: python

Like in the title am I trying to start Blender via Java. It works pretty good. I am on Windows and do the following java command:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "pathToBlendfile\\blendFile.blend").start();
```

I also have a script that does what it should except for a few things. The script seems to be running BEFORE the blender windows are there. It works great with simple things like creating / moving / scaling / etc objects. The problem is with poll()-methods like setting the 3D-Cursor to an object, moving objects to a 3D-cursor etc.

I tried to set sleeps in hope to have Blender fully loaded before the "need 3D-view" part of the script starts but Blender will stay grey until the sleep is over, hit me with several errors and just stops the scripts right there.

I was looking like 2-3 hours for some sort of python-code saying something like "waitTilBlenderIsLoaded()" or something like this.

Does this awesome community have some kind of idea? :(

Thanks for any kind of help!!

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried to launch the blender executable instead of using the registered file extension? Could you also add a simple script that doesn't work for you.

Comment: @stacker No I haven't do you know how the command should be like? And how can I load the file then?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html uses var args this would be "path/blender_executable", "path/blend_file"

Comment: @stacker It does the exact same thing like my old command. It starts blender up to the point where I need the 3D-View to be prominent. There it stops and then it loads the gui.

Comment: I solved the problem as followed: I deleted the "3D cursor to object" and "object to 3D cursor" and changed it for a solid "transform object to position(a, b, c, d)" Cheers!